# CSV to SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

Tags: r, spatial

I have csv which contains 3 columns (latitude ,longitude ,random_colum1,)

now I want to convert that csv to spatial polygon data frame in r. what would be the method for same? thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Start with putting a little data here, ie. `my_data <- read.csv('my_data.file', headers = TRUE)`, then `dput(head(my_data), n =3)`, then copy `structure(` and everything to the final `)`, paste it into your question, and you have the first part of a [minimal reproducible example -MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), and life goes smoother.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.